# Facebook Messenger Channel is not working with Microsoft Botframework

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

In [Microsoft's Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com), there is Facebook Messenger Channel. And according to the setup page, i followed everything and then have finished configuring things on both Bot Framework and Facebook App ends.

Finished setting up Facebook Webhooks and it's Callback URL (with the required Verify Token). Everything seems to be correct (Please refer to screenshots below)

But when i start trying to chat to my page (from my FB Admin Account), there's no reply, nothing.

What seems to be the problem? And what should i be looking at, please?

Thanks all in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found [this walkthrough](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110201/Creating-A-Facebook-Bot-Using-Microsoft-Bot-Framew) very useful for setting up the FB channel

Comment: Is the bot deployed? Where?

Comment: And you see any errors in the BotFramework portal page? (after refreshing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now.

- Inside the Botframework's "Enter your credentials" section, there's `Facebook Page Id` field to enter, but i didn't know there's a specific `Page ID` for a Facebook Page (which can be found under "About" tab). In fact, i thought it was the one we used in the URL (For example: https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx, and therefore: `xxxxxxxxxxx`) but it was wrong.
- Then, deauthorized and resubmitted credentials from Botframework.

Thanks everyone for all the helps.

Comment: It looks like it's the same id, which is used in URL: try pasting it after facebook.com/xxxx .
What do you mean by deauthorizing and resubmitting credentials from Botframework?
I can't get my chatbot work on FB. It does work on Skype and via emulator.

Comment: The ID you see in the URL is not really the `Facebook Page Id`. You can see the correct one only in the "About" tab.

Comment: Go there: https://www.facebook.com/pg/xxxxxxxxxx/about/?ref=page_internal

Answer (score 0):

Also, can you verify that your bot works correctly from the test panel and webchat control in the Bot Framework portal.

You may also wish to deauthorize and resubmit credentials.

it's odd that you're not seeing any errors in the bot framework portal for the Facebook channel, that would almost imply to me that the messages aren't making it from the Facebook messenger chat service to the Bot Framework.  It looks like you've set the callback URL correctly (from the unmasked part).

You can also hook up Azure App Insights and give us the instrumentation key (via the portal) and we will send any error events to your app insights instance.